# Oracle query to get the results of a particular table using the result obtained from another table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to `Oracle`, so kindly bear with me if the question sounds really naive.

So, I have two tables TableA and TableB which have say just two columns `id, name` for simplicity.

I now want to now get the `id` value for a particular value of `name` in `TableA`. If this would be the only requirement, this query would suffice -

```
SELECT id from TableA WHERE name = 'some_name';
```

Now, what I want to do is take this `id` and delete all the rows in `TableB` that match this `id`-

```
DELETE FROM TableB WHERE id = <id obtained from the above query>;
```

What is the composite query in oracle that would perform this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that only a single `id` value is going to be returned for a particular `name` value, you'd just do

```
DELETE FROM tableB b
 WHERE b.id = (SELECT a.id
                 FROM tableA a
                WHERE a.name = 'some_name')
```

Note that the aliases are optional.  However, adding aliases generally makes things clearer so no one has to guess which `id` or which `name` you're referring to at any point.

If there might be multiple `id` values in `tableA` for a given name, you'd just use an `IN` rather than an `=`

```
DELETE FROM tableB b
 WHERE b.id IN (SELECT a.id
                  FROM tableA a
                 WHERE a.name = 'some_name')
```

This would also work if you knew that the query against `tableA` was only going to return one row.  I'd prefer the equality query if you're sure that only one row would be returned, though.  I'd generally rather get an error if my expectations were violated rather than potentially having unexpected rows get deleted.